# MVC Linq Queries and MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2012, asp.net-mvc-5

My question is a fairly straightforward, how to limit columns passed to a View?

Typically when writing SQL a SELECT statement will specify the columns as well as the table(s) required, where as my use of Linq thus far involved inkoing a query like so:

```
var navigationModel = (from m in db.Navigations where (m.Main == true) orderby m.Position select m);
```

This would therefore show all columns identified in the following class:

```
public partial class Navigation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Position { get; set; }
    public bool Main { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
}
```

Therefore the above Linq query is not being very efficient as I only want the columns Title, Action and Controller.

Could someone please show me how to filter data being passed to a view?

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 5):

Create a new `view model` that only has the properties you need:

```
public class NavigationViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

And in your Linq do this to create a collection of your new model class:

```
var navigationModel = from m in db.Navigations 
                      where (m.Main == true) 
                      orderby m.Position 
                      select new NavigationViewModel //This is the new bit
                      {
                          Title = m.Title,
                          Action = m.Action
                      };
```